# Adding Image as Background in tkinter Window with X- and Y- Scrollbars

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, background-image, photoimage

I am working on a **Python 3** *tkinter* app that uses windows with vertical and horizontal (mouse-scrollable) scrollbars along the window's dimensions. But I am unable to display a *.png* image as the background on the same windows.

I've gone through the methods to add a *.png* image as the background using a label and canvas but instead of the picture, I can only see white on regions of the window not covered by the frames. Also I find the canvas method really hard as it becomes very difficult to place frames on it which in turn have labels, buttons, scrollbars etc. I've also tried using *PIL* module but I'm finding trouble importing it from its path (I also don't think it would help much as I'm only trying to use a *.png* image).

**Any suggestions on how to have both the scrollbars and the background image working in the same tkinter window?**

```
#Function to create tkinter window with horizontal and vertical scrollbars

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
def win():
    r0=Tk()
    r0.title('title')
    f=Frame(r0,bg='BLACK')
    f.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
#Creating canvas for attaching scrollbars
    c=Canvas(f,bg='BLACK')
    c.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    s1=ttk.Scrollbar(f, orient=VERTICAL, command=c.yview)
    s2=ttk.Scrollbar(f, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=c.xview)
    s1.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    c.configure(yscrollcommand=s1.set)
    s2.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    c.configure(xscrollcommand=s1.set)
    c.bind('<Configure>', lambda e:c.configure(scrollregion=c.bbox('all')))
#Function to enable mouse scroll
    def mw(event):
        c.yview_scroll(-1*int((event.delta/120)), 'units')
    c.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', mw)
    r=Frame(c, bg='BLACK')
    c.create_window((0,0),window=r, anchor='s')
    return r, r0
r,r0=win()
```

```
#Adding images as background in tkinter window using labels

r=Tk()
# Adjust size 
r.geometry("800x800")
bg=PhotoImage(file="Your_img.png")
# Show image using label
l1 = Label(r, image=bg)
l1.place(x=0, y=0)
```

```
#Adding images as background in tkinter window using canvas

r=Tk()
# Adjust size 
r.geometry("800x800")
bg=PhotoImage(file="Your_img.png")
c1=Canvas(r, width=800, height=800)
c1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
# Display image
c1.create_image(0, 0, image=bg, anchor="nw")
```

Comment: The "white regions" is due to this common problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks! I assumed that it wasn't working due to the presence of an expanding canvas in the window. I added global to the image variable definition in the function and it worked.